# Where is Vernon Roche in For Tameria?

Tags: the-witcher-2

In the quest, For Tameria!, where is Vernon Roche when I have to decide between him and Triss? The quest tracker on the map seems useless as I don't see him anywhere in the market square!

How do I find him?

Answer (score 2):

He should be standing by a large column.[image]

Comment: @pinckerman Interesting avatar ;-)